# Solve JPQL Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I am trying to get details of Properties details from database using JPQL, Hear I am writing where  condition like    *(properties.IsDeleted <> 'Y' or properties.IsDeleted IS NULL)*
but, in JPQL query it is not getting '**Y**', but, it is was showing like '**?**' symbol. this is the problem I am getting. please help me from this issue.

the below code is showing query like:-

> select properties0_.property_id as col_0_0_,
> properties0_.property_type as col_1_0_, properties0_.property_name as
> col_2_0_, properties0_.property_area as col_3_0_,
> properties0_.property_city as col_4_0_, properties0_.no_of_rooms as
> col_5_0_ from iot_property properties0_ where
> (**properties0_.is_deleted<>?** or properties0_.is_deleted is null) and
> properties0_.property_id=6

In the above query in bold mark shows **properties0_.is_deleted<>?** ,but what I want is **properties0_.is_deleted<>Y**

why that **"Y"** is not assigned to that query. that I am not understanding.
will you please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

```
 CriteriaBuilder deviceBuilder = propertySession.getCriteriaBuilder();
                    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> userCriteriaQuery = deviceBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
                    Root<Properties> propertyRoot = userCriteriaQuery.from(Properties.class);
                    Path<Object> pathPropertyId = propertyRoot.get("propertyId");
                    Path<Object> pathpropertyType = propertyRoot.get("propertyType");
                    Path<Object> pathpropertyName = propertyRoot.get("propertyName");
                    Path<Object> pathpropertyArea = propertyRoot.get("propertyArea");
                    Path<Object> pathpropertyCity = propertyRoot.get("propertyCity");
                    Path<Object> pathnumberOfRooms = propertyRoot.get("numberOfRooms");
                    userCriteriaQuery.multiselect(pathPropertyId, pathpropertyType, pathpropertyName, pathpropertyArea,
                            pathpropertyCity, pathnumberOfRooms);

Predicate userRestriction = deviceBuilder.or(deviceBuilder.notEqual(propertyRoot.get("isDelete"), "Y"),
                        deviceBuilder.isNull(propertyRoot.get("isDelete")));
                Predicate userRestriction2 = deviceBuilder
                        .and(deviceBuilder.equal(propertyRoot.get("propertyId"), propertyId));
                userCriteriaQuery.where(deviceBuilder.and(userRestriction, userRestriction2));
                
                Query<Object[]> deviceQuery = propertySession.createQuery(userCriteriaQuery);
                List<Object[]> resultList =deviceQuery.getResultList();
                for(Object[] objects : resultList) {
                    Integer dbPropertyId = (Integer) objects[0];
                    String dbPropertyType = (String) objects[1];
                    String  dbpropertyName = (String) objects[2];
                    String dbpropertyArea = (String) objects[3];
                    String dbpropertyCity = (String) objects[4];
                    Integer dbNoOfRooms = (Integer) objects[5];
                    System.out.println(dbPropertyId);
                    System.out.println(dbPropertyType);
                    System.out.println(dbpropertyName);
                    System.out.println(dbpropertyArea);
                    System.out.println(dbpropertyCity);
                    System.out.println(dbNoOfRooms);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "the final JPQL that ultimately gets translated to the final SQL with inserted paramerters". **How a JPA implementation generates the SQL is down to it, and parameters, in general, will never be substituted into any String. SQL has generated from expression trees etc, not a String**. This is a criteria query so for parameters it will show **"?"** on the console.

If you want param values inserting in then do it yourself since it only makes sense to you